# TextView turns black when setTextColor method is called

Tags: android, textview

TextView turns black or near black  when setTextColor is called. Not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Currently using holo.light.

```
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

Set my TextView as follows

```
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="0"
          android:id="@+id/tvOutput"
          android:textColor="@color/button_text"
          android:textSize="70dp" android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
          android:gravity="center"/>
```

The issue arises when i try to call  tvOutput.setTextColor(R.color.laserblue); R.color.laserblue  as: #ff00ddff  However, it turns black! I'm clueless as to why it does this. For any color i try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call

`getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR)` to set a color properly.

use The Following Code to Set The Color

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURCOLOR));
```